# ReactJS: Display value in Alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alertify

I'm trying to create an alert with value, but it is always displayed like: [object object]

```
 alertify.confirm(
      "Confirm your data",
      utility._htmlToString(utility._html(utility.t("REGISTRATION_CONFIRM1"))) + <b>{formRegistrazione.values.FiscalCode}</b>,
```

this    `{formRegistrazione.values.FiscalCode}`  is displayed like [object object], how can I display the value?

Comment: is `FiscalCode` a proper string?

Comment: You can't display objects in html or in alerts you have to specify the value you want from the object like `object.item` or just use `JSON.stringify(object)`.

Comment: I have tried to use JSON.stringify(formRegistrazione.values.FiscalCode), but It is displayed always like [object object]

Comment: @Greedo I have tried to console.log and it is a Object

Comment: check what is in the object

Comment: @Jack23 So it won't work, it needs to be a string or to have a `toString()` method

Comment: ```console.log(JSON.stringify(formRegistrazione.values.FiscalCode))```

Answer (score 1):

```
alertify.confirm(
  'Confirm Message' + {formRegistrazione.values.FiscalCode}</b>, 
  () => { alertify.success('Ok') }, 
  () => { alertify.error('Cancel')}
)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your object - formRegistrazione.values.FiscalCode - should have at least one key/value pair.
ie,

```
const FiscalCode = { foo: 'bar' }
```

So to print the value 'bar' you would type formRegistrazione.values.FiscalCode.foo.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you suggest to do